# C++ copy initialization + implicit constructor call = fail

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, implicit-conversion, copy-initialization

This code:

```
class foo
{
    int x;
public:
    foo(int x) : x(x) { }
    int get() const { return x; }
    //...
};

class bar
{
    int x;
public:
    bar(const foo& x) : x(x.get()) { }
    int get() const { return x; }
    bar& operator =(const foo& rhs) { x = rhs.get(); return *this; }
    //...
};

void func()
{
    foo f = 3;
    bar b = 3;
    b = 7;
    //...
}
```

errors out on the `bar b = 3` line (g++ 4.7.1 with `-fstd=gnu++11`):

```
error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'bar' requested
```

However, I'm providing a `bar` constructor that takes a `foo`, and ints can be implicitly converted to `foo` as shown by the line preceding it. So, what is going wrong?

By the way, for several reasons it is undesirable to force conversion to `foo` using `foo(3)` because that would make my actual code ugly to use and read.

Comment: C++ allows no implicit conversion path that involves more than one user-defined conversion.

Comment: @n.m.: That's an _answer_ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm providing a bar constructor that takes a foo, and ints can be implicitly converted to foo as shown by the line preceding it. So, what is going wrong?

Chained-conversion is not allowed in C++, which means the (chained) conversion cannot occur:

```
int -> foo -> bar  //not allowed (chained conversion)
```

even though the followings are given:

```
int -> foo  //given
foo -> bar  //given
```

So if you want `int -> bar` to work, then add another constructor taking `int` to class `bar`.

Comment: I guess I should also add an `operator =(int)` overload so that the assignment is not ambiguous.

Comment: @fincs: If you add `bar(int)`, then you don't need to add `operator=(int)`.

Comment: Yes I do, the compiler complains: `error: ambiguous overload for \`operator=\` in \`b = 7\``.

Comment: @fincs: Oh, you have `operator=(foo const&)` which is causing ambigious. I didn't see this before.

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm actually trying to figure out why the assignment works while the copy-initialization doesn't. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @AndyProwl: `operator=` are not considered user-defined conversion function. So there is only one conversion taking place for assignment. Note that `b=7` is same as `b.operator=(7)` which is conceptually same as `b.some_function_taking_foo(7)`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Interesting. Do you happen to know where is this specified? 13.3.3.1/1 says: "An implicit conversion sequence is a sequence of conversions used to convert an argument in a function call
to the type of the corresponding parameter of the function being called".

Comment: @AndyProwl: Search for *"converting constructor"* in the spec, and *user-defined conversion*.

Comment: @Nawaz: Ok, I got it. Here the target type of the conversion is `foo`, while in the copy-initialization the target type is `bar`. I somehow assumed `operator =` takes a `bar const&`, I should learn to read.

Answer (score 0):

§ 13.3.3.1.2/1 about implicit user-defined conversion sequences mandates:

> **A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by a user defined conversion (12.3) followed by a second standard conversion sequence**. If the user-defined conversion is specified by a constructor (12.3.1), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the type required by the argument of the constructor. If the user-defined conversion is specified by a conversion function (12.3.2), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the implicit object parameter of the conversion function.

This means it is not possible to chain more than one user-defined conversion.